# for-loop LaTeX \i subtract

Tags: latex

Currently, I'm working in LaTeX and want to make labels with a for-loop. For a certain reason I want to use the for-loop which goes from 4 to 7.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \foreach \i in {4,...,7}
        {
            \draw(0, -\i) node[anchor=north west] {Elektrode\textsubscript{\i-4} +};
        }
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

What I want is that it will output: Elektrode0; Elektrode1, Elektrode2, Elektrode3
But what I get is: Elektrode4-4; Elektrode5-4, Elektrode6-4, Elektrode7-4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please make a [mre]. You've been asked this before!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz My sincere apologies. I forgot to copy all the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible approaches, but one easy workaround is to use a second variable:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \foreach[count = \x from 0 ] \i in {4,...,7}
        {
            \draw(0, -\i) node[anchor=north west] {Elektrode\textsubscript{\x} +};
        }
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```